# High temperature+humidty and electronics

Tags: arduino, temperature, humidity

I am using a temperature sensor and accompanying devices to prototype a circuit which will be placed in high temperature and humidity conditions. Temperatures up to 40°C and humidity up to 75%. Do I need to make considerations here regarding safety and efficiency or are these conditions not significant enough? I am most worried about humidity as I have found that the temperature I will expose these things to are well within limits of most electronics.

In particular I am wondering, does all wiring need to be insulated and do integrated circuits (such as an Arduino) need to be covered in some way?

As an example, I am using the following temperature sensor which needs to be wired to an Arduino. Does the temperature sensor itself have to be insulated as well ??

[image: AM2302]

Comment: I think you should be fine. High humidity is common in a lot fo places and unless you get large temperature differences it should be ok. 40C is still quite cool for most electronics.

Comment: That temperature and humidity... is like in my pocket.   It's not extreme.

Comment: How long must this system function in the humidity? When NASA/TRW et al build satellites, they often build several identical satellites and place the extras in long-term storage. To ensure the equipment works, after 20 years in storage, the PCBs are conformal-coated to exclude humidity to prevent fungal growth.

Answer (score 1):

Check the datasheet of any device for electrical specifications OR the manufactures website. Sometimes information is listed by package type. There are some sensors (a lot of mems devices) that are sensitive to moisture especially before manufacture (high temp in an oven).

Most electronics operating temperature is at least 80C (again check the datasheet for max *operating temperature*), some parts max temp need to be derated if they consume a lot of power (like transistors).

The biggest concert with humidity is condensation which will create shorting and corrosion. If this is a concern, you will have to protect your electronics from condensation. Most parts don't have a humidity rating but they will tell you if they do.

> In particular I am wondering, does all wiring need to be insulated and
>   do integrated circuits (such as an Arduino) need to be covered in some
>   way?

Wiring should be insulated to protect against shorting. Insulating an enclosure will only protect against

> As an example, I am using the following temperature sensor which needs
>   to be wired to an Arduino. Does the temperature sensor itself have to
>   be insulated as well ??

This temperature sensor needs to be exposed to the air to get a correct reading, the wires need to be insulated to protect against shorting.